# SQL query to return value based on value in row

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to popullate a column based on another column.

For example

```
SELECT name, age, (select count(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE name = **value in column [name]**) FROM PEOPLE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes but not with that syntax. Do you have some sample data? I would suggest joining the tables or using a subquery to get the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but you have to use proper aliases for the tables:

```
SELECT 
  p.name, 
  p.age, 
  (select count(*) FROM ORDERS o WHERE o.name = p.name)  counter
FROM PEOPLE p
```

so the 2 columns from different tables both having the same name `name` can be distinguished.

As suggested by Larnu, try this alternative which does the same by joining the tables and aggregating:

```
SELECT 
  p.name, 
  p.age, 
  count(o.name) counter
FROM PEOPLE p LEFT JOIN ORDERS o
ON o.name = p.name
GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better served with a `JOIN` and aggregation? The subquery will likely result in multiple scans of `ORDERS`.

Comment: I'm not sure about it. There are cases where such embedded queries are more efficient. Anyway this answer is based on the OP's code. The explanation about the aliases I think is more useful than a point to another direction

Comment: Thanks guys! You've been a massive help